# generate next number using the last data inserted into mysql table

Tags: php, mysqli

My database has a table named **tbltest** . in this there is column **id** that is set to auto increment and another column is named as **app_id** .

What i want here is i want to generate app_id when someone visit My Form page Called **apply.php** and submit application form there. is it possible to get the last inserted id in table and get the corresponding app_id generated for that id and generate new app_id on submit the form page.

[image]

Now As there is last inserted id is 1 and app_id is IVISA250531 , So, When We Submit the form, it Should generate Next app_id that Should be,

**IVISA250532**

Comment: Have you tried to set app_id as AUTO_INCREMENT in mysql?

Comment: Why do you want 2 fields to be auto incremented - they will have the same values anyway so you can just use ID.

Comment: @StefanAvramovic Have you noticed that the value starts with the string `IVISA`? How can it be auto-increment?

Comment: @RacilHilan By removing IVISA..

Comment: @StefanAvramovic If you're making such a radical change to the value, then you might as well go with your second suggestion of using only one auto-incremented column, which I generally agree with.

Comment: @StefanAvramovic : i dont want to remove string from app_id .that is the problem.

Comment: @RacilHilan then you culd go like app_id = IVISA+id

Comment: @StefanAvramovic : mate, is this the only solution for this.

Comment: @StefanAvramovic Yeah, obviously. But if the `app_id` field is  foreign key for example, then you cannot do that. Anyway, this question is too broad and we need more detail to be able to answer it correctly. As it stands now, it's not answerable and should be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can **do**:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbltest ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ;

    $str = $row["app_id"];//"IVISA250532";
    $int = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '',$str);//to get the Int from string '250532'
    $pure_str = str_replace($int, "", $str);// tog get only the string word 'IVISA'

    $Next_app_id = $pure_str.($int+1); // << that is what you need "IVISA250533"
}
```

Comment: Mohamed Saed : Thanks Mate ! it worked like charm, it is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php 

    class operation{

        public function contains($id, $app_id){

           $match ="IVISA";

           preg_match_all('/^([^\d]+)(\d+)/', $app_id, $match);

                $text = $match[1][0];
                $num = $match[2][0];
                $newid = $num+$id;
                return  $text.$newid;
        }


    }

    $str = new operation;
    $app_id = $str->contains(10, "IVISA1005050421321");
   echo $app_id;

    ?>
```

Comment: Result: IVISA1005050421331

Comment: Yes, Result is IVISA1005050421331